# SQL statement in Wordpress

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I'm trying to run an SQL statement on a Wordpress page. I've already tested it in the phpmyadmin and that works:

```
SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_value = "9bf2c7f9760393fa83e65ad455e00243"
```

The result on this is the post_id 20

**This is my code in the Wordpress template:**

```
<?php
    global $wpdb;
    $uniqueId = $_GET['id'];

    $getPostId = $wpdb->get_var(
        $wpdb->prepare("SELECT post_id FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "wp_postmeta WHERE meta_value = %d", $uniqueId)
    );
    

    echo $getPostId;
?>
```

It should echo the value 20, but it does nothing. I've also tested if the variable `$uniqueId` is set and that's the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with your code.

**1.** You have a typo in your query:

```
"SELECT post_id FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "wp_postmeta WHERE meta_value = %d"
```

Should be:

```
"SELECT post_id FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "postmeta WHERE meta_value = %d"
```

You're repeating the `wp_` prefix twice:

```
... $wpdb->prefix . "wp_postmeta WHERE ...
```

**2.** [As Mike pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64715679/9131961), `%d` expects an integer. Your code suggests it should be a string so you should be using `%s` instead:

```
$getPostId = $wpdb->get_var(
    $wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT post_id FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "postmeta WHERE meta_value = %s",
        $uniqueId
    )
);
```

Updated code:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$uniqueId = $_GET['id'];

$getPostId = $wpdb->get_var(
    $wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT post_id FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "postmeta WHERE meta_value = %s",
        $uniqueId
    )
);

echo $getPostId;
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works ! A stupid mistake from me.

Comment: Don't worry about it. Even the most seasoned developer makes mistakes every single day :P Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

The %d placeholder in the prepare statement expects an integer. But you are assigning a string. So in this case you should use the string placeholder which is %s.

New code:

```
<?php
    global $wpdb;
    $uniqueId = $_GET['id'];

    $getPostId = $wpdb->get_var(
        $wpdb->prepare("SELECT post_id FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "wp_postmeta WHERE meta_value = %s", $uniqueId)
    );
    

    echo $getPostId;
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but still no result.

Comment: Tried it with get_row? And then echo $getPostId->post_id